# "Single-threaded apartment mode" error using OPENROWSET with Excel

Tags: sql-server, openrowset

I have an Excel file. I need to import that Excel file into SQL Server, I am using this Query

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
     'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Users\Jojin\Desktop\Products.xls', [Sheet1$])
```

But I am getting error like:

> Msg 7308, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 OLE DB provider
>   'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be used for distributed queries
>   because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment
>   mode.

Comment: Check this article http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/11/03/sql-server-fix-error-ms-jet-oledb-4-0-cannot-be-used-for-distributed-queries-because-the-provider-is-used-to-run-in-apartment-mode/